# .NET native windows store release

Tags: c#, .net, windows, release, win-universal-app

I have problem with release version of my application. After retarget windows store app to universal windows platform project i can't run application in release mode with Compile with .NET Native tool chain option checked.

I get an error:

Exception thrown: `System.Reflection.MissingRuntimeArtifactException` in `System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll`

Additional information: `MakeGenericMethod()` cannot create this generic method instantiation because the instantiation was not metadata-enabled: `System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct<System.Char>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Char>)`
For more information, please visit **http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=616868**

When i disable  Compile with .NET Native tool chain application is working and doesn't throw a exception. 
Generally this is solution, but in Windows App Certification Kit i get failed result with errors (Test Supported API):

·API `ExecuteAssembly` in `uwphost.dll` is not supported for this application type. App.exe calls this API. 
·API `DllGetActivationFactory` in `uwphost.dll` is not supported for this application type. App.exe has an export that forwards to this API. 
·API `OpenSemaphore` in `ap-ms-win-core-synch-11-1-0.dll` is not supported for this application type. `System.Threading.dll` calls this API. 
·API `CreateSemaphore` in `api-ms-win-core-kernel32-legacy-11-1-0.dll` is not supported for this application type. `System.Threading.dll` calls this API.

Someone can help?

Comment: This is the one and only reason that you have the .NET Native toolchain installed on your machine.  It lets you test your app so you can find out where you use Reflection.  The kind of code that .NET Native cannot discover by itself.  And the kind of code that will make your app fail once it is installed on the user's device.  You must add the type name of the class to the runtime directives configuration file.  [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/dn600640%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> The .NET Native runtime doesn't include a JIT compiler. As a result, all necessary native code must be generated in advance. A set of heuristics is used to determine what code should be generated, but these heuristics cannot cover all possible metaprogramming scenarios. Therefore, you must provide hints for these metaprogramming scenarios by using runtime directives. If the necessary metadata or implementation code is not available at runtime, your app throws a MissingMetadataException, MissingRuntimeArtifactException, or MissingInteropDataException exception.  Two troubleshooters are available that will generate the appropriate entry for your runtime directives file that eliminates the exception:

- The MissingMetadataException troubleshooter for types.
- The MissingMetadataException troubleshooter for methods.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/dn600640%28v=vs.110%29.aspx